# How do I add a time option on this date javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day

I require some help with this. I have this code for a datepicker and need to add a time option to it as well. I've tried a plugin but then none of my javascript/jquery works.

```
<script>
var dateToday = new Date();                             
$(function() {
$( "#Date1" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: dateToday

   });
});
</script>
```

I tried the following plugin but as I said, then none of my other stuff is working when I'm linking the source of this plugin for the timepicker.

[Plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You May Check This http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at that one. Looks like it could work well.

Comment: I have a question: How do I link to this folder if I put it in on my local folder where my website is hosted? Since I want to store it in a seperate folder, and link to it from all the webpages I have?

Comment: Do You Read The Documentation.

Comment: yeah I did, figured it out. Thanks